# wordpress disable certain plugins for catagory?

Tags: plugins

how do i disable certain plugins for catagory page.

for example
www.example.com/catagory
here it wil list all items posted

extended example
www.example.com/catagory/bikes
here it will show all post of bikes

so i want to remove all wordpress plugins for
www.example.com/catagory
because its making alot of database request to unwanted pluigns that is not even required for this page.

another example what i mean is when we have 10 plugins installed we may use them plugins for certain page ,  contact form7 etc
but i seen contact form7 plugins,files load in other pages when its not even needed there ,  so i used ( plugin optimizer )  which did a good job turning off unwanted plugins for certain pages , how ever am unable to do this task for catagory any suggestions ?

Comment: That's depending on the plugin functions. Say for example social sharing buttons will work on all the pages.  If a plugin runs by a short code it will run on the specific page only.

Comment: how do i disable it for the catagory section as i se so many unwanted plugins load up there

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to do that. If you need different sections of your site to use different plugins then you should consider using wordpress in a network/multisite configuration with every section as a subsite and have different plugins working on each subsite. This of course might create its own set of (different) problems.